# summernote WYSIWYG content not getting to $_POST

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap-3, summernote, bootstrap-wysiwyg

I have been looking for a WYSIWYG editor for bootstrap and I came across summernote.

it seems like a nice light editor for bootstrap.

The problem I am having is that that when I post the form the summernote code from the textarea is stripped out. The text is submitting however.

Does anyone have a workaround to the get summernote to actually post the code it generates.

Answer (score 1):

My bad I had a striptags somewhere in teh php processing that was clearing it duh!

That was a couple of hours wasted.